# При парсинге JSONArray приходит последний в списке Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Получаю через GET запрос json

```
{"data": [
    "Черногория",
    "Чехия",
    "Чили"
]}
```

Как его распарсить если нужно каждую страну вывести в отдельный item. Использую Pojo.

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> data = null;
```

это активити в которой я использую retrofit для подключения, все приходит, но выводит только последнее поле в списки

```
public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Countries countries = response.body();
                if (countries != null) {
                    for (int x =0; x<countries.getData().size(); x++) {
                        arrayList.add(countries);
                        viewAdapterCountry.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }}}
        }
```

а вот адаптер

```
private ArrayList<Countries> countryModels;
    Countries countryModel = countryModels.get(i);
            List<String> country = countryModel.getData();
            for (int x = 0; x<country.size(); x++){
                viewHolder.button.setText(country.get(x));
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделайте так:

```
public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200) {
            Countries countries = response.body();
            if (countries != null) {
                for (int x =0; x<countries.getData().size(); x++) {
                    arrayList.add(countries.getData().get(x));
                }
                 viewAdapterCountry.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found. у меня же в модели и в других классах отличаются массивы, первый раз столкнулся с таким json, другие парсил и ничего, а без полей не понимаю как

Comment: @t_n_n_97 да, я немного ошибся. Тут нужно использовать .`get()`, использование `[]` для `ArrayList` недопустимо

Comment: @t_n_n_97 у Вас получилось? Если да - отметьте ответ принятым, пожалуйста)

Comment: error: no suitable method found for add(String)

Comment: Ошибка в том что разные типы у ArrayList, а как быть по другому? первый раз с таким столкнулся

Comment: так объявите `arrayList` как `ArrayList<String>`. Вам же в нём именно строки нужны, так?

Comment: Сработало) просто я работал с полями в json а тут приходит массив, спасибо) Можно с вами как нибудь связаться не в stackoverflow?

Comment: @t_n_n_97 а что конкретно Вас интересует?

Comment: По архитектуре хотелось бы поговорить, или можете тут написать что лучше посмотреть для android разработки. Если не сложно)

Comment: @t_n_n_97 долгого обсуждения мне бы не хотелось, но могу дать насколько ссылок: 1) интересные каналы в телеграмме https://t.me/kotlin_mobile
https://t.me/startandroidchat
https://t.me/android_ru
https://t.me/Android_Architecture

2) достаточно хороший проект в плане архитектуры (он учебно-тренировочный)
https://gitlab.com/terrakok/gitlab-client

3) очень советую почитать книгу "Чистая архитектура" Мартина. Она в целом про ПО, но современные подходы в Android разработке построены на основе идей этой книги.

Comment: Спасибо большое)